# Creating concave polygon with constraint angles in QGIS

Tags: qgis, concave-hull

I'm having point data. By using that I want to create concave polygon with some constraint angles (i.e., >45 and <225 degree).

Is it possible to do in QGIS?

Comment: I have written a Qgis plugin for generating concave hull, available from the plugin repo. The algorithm used evaluates angles to decide with points to connect. You can refactor the main method from the source and adapt the logic to your needs.

Comment: @Detlev It sounds like you may have the basis for an answer, and I'm sure Pauline would appreciate it if you could post more details about this in an answer.

Comment: @pauline I would take the opportunity and try to include constraints on angles as an option in the plugin. Can you provide me with a test data set and a sample solution of your problem?